# Confusion with array size in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Why does the sizeof (array [0]) return size as 8 when it has 17 characters/bytes within it?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

int main  () {

  char* array [2] = {"12345678912345678","12345678"};
  int a = sizeof  (array [0]);

  fprintf (stdout, "%s , %d \n", array [0], a);

  return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
12345678912345678 , 12345678
```

Comment: I think you may be getting the size of the pointer, rather than the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the length of the actual character string being stored, use

`printf("%lu", strlen(array[0]));`

This gives `17`.

Make sure to include the `<string.h>` header.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof(array [0])` returns the size of the **pointer** which is depend your system. Use `strlen()` function to get your expected output.

```
  int a = strlen(array [0]);
```

Comment: Prefer Clint's answer, but appreciated. Thanks.